# Set function attribute from JSON?

Tags: python, attributes

I'm running into some issues with a part of my code. I'm trying to definse a function that would take data from JSON, and use it to set an attribute.

Part of the code is based on a library from Adafruit, Adafruit_CircuitPython_MCP230xx.

The code I am running with at the moment looks as follows:

```
import time
import board
import busio
import digitalio
from adafruit_mcp230xx.mcp23017 import MCP23017
i2c = busio.I2C(board.SCL, board.SDA)
mcp = MCP23017(i2c)

pin0 = mcp.get_pin(0)
pin0.switch_to_output(value=True)
```

At this point, I will fetch the data from a long list of pins from JSON, and will attempt to set an attribute. An example that will work, looks like this:

```
pin0.value = True
```

However, my part would look roughly like this:

```
dataJSON['pin'].value = True
```

This however does not seem to work. I've also tried going the route of:

```
setattr(dataJSON['pin'], 'value')
```

But this was not working either. I'm slowing running out of idea's on how to best move forward.

Comment: `dataJSON['pin'] = True` ?

Comment: Do you mean that `dataJSON['pin']` will result in the string `'pin0'`?

Comment: That is correct, yes. @mkrieger17